# Android: App crash while trying to get AppBarLayout LayoutParams

Tags: android, android-toolbar, android-collapsingtoolbarlayout, android-appbarlayout

I am having a ClassCastException while trying to set AppBarLayout params. Below is my XML code

```
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    tools:context="com.example.testapp.ConsoleActivity">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="280dp"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay"
        android:id="@+id/app_bar_layout">

        <android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout
            android:id="@+id/collapsing_toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            app:contentScrim="?attr/colorPrimary"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|exitUntilCollapsed">

            <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="220dp"
                android:id="@+id/app_bar_account_cards_pager"
                app:layout_collapseMode="parallax"
                android:layout_marginTop="?attr/actionBarSize" />

            <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
                android:id="@+id/toolbar"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
                android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
                app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay"
                app:layout_collapseMode="pin" />

        </android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout>

    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:clipToPadding="false"
        android:id="@+id/nested_scroll_bar"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior">

        <include layout="@layout/content_console"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"/>

    </android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView>



</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

And I am trying to get instance of AppBarLayoutParams using following java code

```
Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
AppBarLayout.LayoutParams p = (AppBarLayout.LayoutParams) toolbar.getLayoutParams();
p.setScrollFlags(0);
toolbar.setLayoutParams(p);
```

But I am getting `java.lang.ClassCastException: android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout$LayoutParams cannot be cast to android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout$LayoutParams` with this line `AppBarLayout.LayoutParams p = (AppBarLayout.LayoutParams) toolbar.getLayoutParams();`. How can I solve this?

Comment: Your toolbar is inside a `android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout`

Comment: Use CollapsingToolbarLayout in place of AppBarLayout.

Comment: that's because your toolbar is not inside AppBarLayout, but inside CollapsingToolbarLayout

Comment: @EduardoHerzer @Chetan @Vlad Matvienko Ok. Now I tried to cast with `CollapsingToolbarLayout.LayoutParams` but that doesn't offer `setScrollFlags()` functionality which I actually need. how can I solve this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have to Cast with

```
android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout.LayoutParams
```

instead of

```
android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout.LayoutParams
```

Edit: layout params are provided by the view's immidiate parents

```
CollapsingToolbarLayout collapsingToolbar = (CollapsingToolbarLayout) findViewById(R.id.collapsing_toolbar);
AppBarLayout.LayoutParams p = (AppBarLayout.LayoutParams) collapsingToolbar.getLayoutParams();
p.setScrollFlags(0);
collapsingToolbar.setLayoutParams(p);
```

Comment: But `android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout.LayoutParams` doesn't offer `setScrollFlags()` functionality which I actually need. It says can not resolve method?

Comment: Apply findViewById on collapsing_toolbar and take layout params from it.

Comment: I didn't understand. I casted with `android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout.Layout‌​Params` and got an instance of `CollapsingToolbarLayout.LayoutParams` but this inctance doesn't offer `setScrollFlags()` method which I need to set. The `AppBarLayout.LayoutParams` has this method how ever.

Comment: I just tried out your edited code. It working fine. Thank you very much